# Generate associated record when another record is marked as 'complete' Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a several models in Rails that are associated like so:

```
class Scan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :ats
end

class At < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :scans
end
```

My question is:
How do I have Rails generate an AT when Scan is marked as 'complete' by the user? An AT should be generated that is associated with the scan that has been marked as 'complete'.

Updated:
Scan is being marked as 'complete' using boolean

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you marking a `Scan` as complete?

Comment: @gabrielhilal I've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like the following:

```
class Scan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :ats
  after_update :generate_at

  private

  def generate_at
    return unless self.complete
    self.ats.create!
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I'll give this a shot